# caesar cipher in python no output

Tags: python-3.x, function, encryption, caesar-cipher

```
def encrypt(sent,n):
    ''' caesar cipher, insert a sent to encrypt it '''
    # if the shift digit is more than the number of chars to shift, will ask for input again
    if n > 128:
        encryption_digit = int(input("Please insert a number of digits less than 129"))
        encrypt(sent,encryption_digit)
    # makes a list of all the chars
    lis1 = [chr(i) for i in range(128)]    
    # this will be the encrypted list (Reordered list )
    lis2 = []
    # this is the output , the encrypted sentence
    secret = ""
    # a counter to map the chars between the two lists
    con = 0
    # reordering the first list, and appending it into the second list
    for i in lis1[-n:]:
        lis2.append(i)        
    for i in lis1[0:128-n]:
        lis2.append(i)
    # comparing the char in the sentence and the char in lis1 to make the secret sentence
    for l in sent:
        for r in lis1:
            # this will set the counter back to 0, so the lis2[con] won't go out of range
            if con > 128:
                con = 0
            
            if r == l:
                secret = secret + lis2[con]
            else:
                con += 1
    return secret
    
password = input("Insert password\n--> ")
# the number of shifts you want to make
encryption_digit = int(input("What's your caesar cipher shift number\n--> "))
encrypt(password, encryption_digit)
```

So like I am not getting any output; I know that I still have to set more conditions to make it perfect and get rid out of all possible errors, but this code ain't working.by the way, I am still new to commenting sorry, but if you could also give me feedback on my comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `encrypt()` returns a value instead of printing a value. Because of that, you must put the function inside `print()` when calling it so that the value returned, gets outputted to the standard output.

```py
print(encrypt(password, encryption_digit))
```